# How to Home a stepper and make it move 45 degree after that

Tags: stepper

I am trying to let a stepper find home (via microswitch) after power up. After that make it move 45 degrees (or the equivalent in steps) and wait for 3 seconds. Below is the code i found/adapted.

The setup part kind of works, but does not run smoothly.

The stepper1() part does not work at all (only jerking movements).

I would also like the motor to be disable when it waits which in my understanding should be achieved by `digitalWrite(M2en,HIGH);`but when I place this at the beginning and end (LOW, HIGH) of stepper1() it never worked. Any ideas would be great.

```
#include "AccelStepper.h"

int M2dirpin = 4;  //Motor Y direction pin
int M2steppin = 5; //Motor Y step pin
int M2en=12;  //Motor Y enable pin
#define home_switch 9 // Pin 9 connected to Home Switch (MicroSwitch)

// AccelStepper Setup
AccelStepper stepperX(1, 5, 4);   // (1,2,3) = (Dedicated Board, STEP, DIR)
// Stepper Travel Variables
long initial_homing = -1; // Used to Home Stepper at startup


void setup() {

  pinMode(home_switch, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(M2dirpin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2steppin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2en,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(M2en,LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Start the Serial monitor with speed of 9600 Bauds
  stepperX.setMaxSpeed(50.0);      // Set Max Speed of Stepper (Slower to get better accuracy)
  stepperX.setAcceleration(50.0);  // Set Acceleration of Stepper

  // Start Homing procedure of Stepper Motor at startup
  Serial.print("Stepper is Homing . . . . . . . . . . . ");

  while (digitalRead(home_switch)) {  // Make the Stepper move CCW until the switch is activated
    stepperX.moveTo(initial_homing);  // Set the position to move to
    initial_homing--;  // Decrease by 1 for next move if needed
    stepperX.run();  // Start moving the stepper
    delay(20);
  }

  stepperX.setCurrentPosition(0);  // Set the current position as zero for now
  stepperX.setMaxSpeed(50.0);      // Set Max Speed of Stepper (Slower to get better accuracy)
  stepperX.setAcceleration(50.0);  // Set Acceleration of Stepper
  initial_homing = 1;

  while (!digitalRead(home_switch)) { // Make the Stepper move CW until the switch is deactivated
    stepperX.moveTo(initial_homing);
    stepperX.run();
    initial_homing++;
    delay(20);
  }

  stepperX.setCurrentPosition(0);
  Serial.println("Homing Completed");
  Serial.println("");

 // Move 10 steps forward from the limit switch (to get out of the switch)
  while (stepperX.currentPosition() != 10) 
  {
    stepperX.setSpeed(10);
    stepperX.run();

}
}
void loop()
{
//stepper1();
}

void stepper1() 
{
  stepperX.move(22.5);
  stepperX.run();
  delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `run` more often. From the [documentation](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/classAccelStepper.html#a608b2395b64ac15451d16d0371fe13ce):

> You must call this as frequently as possible, but at least once per minimum step time interval, preferably in your main loop. Note that each call to run() will make at most one step, and then only when a step is due, based on the current speed and the time since the last step.

So a single `run` call and then a delay, will make the motor move only one step. So you need to rewrite for example:

```
stepperX.run();
delay(3000);
```

to

```
unsigned long startMillis = millis();
while( millis()-startMillis<3000 )
{
  stepperX.run();
}
```

Secondly, `move` only works on integers, `stepperX.move(22.5);` will actually become `stepperX.move(22);`

Lastly, why are you using a totally different method from the rest, to move the motor 10 steps? I'd use a moveTo(10), like you are using everywhere else.